# UIBezierPath strokecolor outline when drawing

Tags: ios, drawing, uibezierpath

I'm doing some tests with freehand drawing for an App. I've implemented a line draw and and erase draw method.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.addingImage drawInRect:rect];
    [self.path stroke];
    self.path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;

    if (self.isEraseMode)
    {
        [[UIColor clearColor] setStroke];
        [self.path setLineWidth:self.eraseWidth];
        [self.path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeClear alpha:1.0];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.strokeColor setStroke];
        [self.path setLineWidth:self.strokeWidth];
        [self.path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    }
}
```

The app draws well, but I've seen a dark outline while I'm drawing which disappear when touch ended.

[image: While drawing]

[image: After drawing]

Is there a way to avoid this outline when drawing?

Thanks.

Comment: I think `[self.path stroke];` should be added in the end.

Comment: Did it work? Then I should add it as answer ?

Comment: Yes, it work! Add it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bezier path should be drawn in the end, in your case you are doing it in the beginning, `[self.path stroke];` should be added in the end.

That should work.

Cheers.